# Uncaught TypeError: FeatureLayer is not a constructor

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, feature-layer

I am trying to test adding a clickable layer to a web app. I am just using a test layer from arcgis online rest services shown in a tutorial. When I try to add the layer using `esri/FeatureLayer` I, get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: FeatureLayer is not a constructor
```

Any suggestions on what the problem might be? Below is just my simple test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Intro to MapView - Create a 2D map</title>
<style>
  html, body, #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/"></script>
<script>
  require([
    "esri/Map", 
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "dojo/domReady!",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
  ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer){
    var map = new Map({
      basemap: "streets"
    });
    var view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",  // Reference to the scene div created in step 5
      map: map,  // Reference to the map object created before the scene
      zoom: 4,  // Sets zoom level based on level of detail (LOD)
      center: [15, 65]  // Sets center point of view using longitude,latitude
    });
    var featureLayer = new 
    FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3);   
    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    featureLayer.on('click',function(e){   
      var specific = e.graphic.attributes['SpecificAttribute']   
      window.open("http://brazostacos.com/wp/"+specific);  
    })
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- The parameters of the main function don't line up with the names in require, you would need for instance `function (Map, MapView, domReady, FeatureLayer)`, or change the order of the requires.
- The method `addLayers()` does not exists in the JavaScript api version 4. Are you using the version 3 api documentation by any chance? Use `map.layers.add()`.
- You are missing a quote in the FeatureLayer's constructor
- The script is incomplete, it would have helped if you copied the entire (test) page